# Weird JSON (Logic) Error?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

Hello Android programmers,

I am working on parsing a website in my application.

This is the website: https://raw.github.com/currencybot/open-exchange-rates/master/latest.json

The problem with this code segment is that it is not getting the rates **in order**.

```
    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Double>>
{
    protected ArrayList<Double> doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        ArrayList<Double> response = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (String url : urls)
        {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try
            {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(content);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                while (isr.read(buffer) != -1)
                {
                    sb.append(buffer);
                }
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                JSONObject ratesObj = jobj.getJSONObject("rates");
                Iterator<String> keys = ratesObj.keys();
                while (keys.hasNext())
                {
                    response.add(Double.parseDouble(ratesObj.getString(keys.next())));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Double> result)
    { 
        currency_values = result;
    }
```

To test this class, I used the following line of code:

```
   test.setText(currency_values.get(0).toString()); //test is a TextView
```

The answer should be 3.6733 (if you look at the website), because it is the first rate in the ArrayList. However, it returns 82.894997, which is later found under JPY.

Why would this be happening? Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be because JSONObject is probably using a simple Map (not a sorted one) to store the field/value combinations. The solution is to update your JSON, actually. The problem is that you want an array of rates. Like this:

```
 "rates": [
    { "AED": 3.6733 },
    {"AFN": 48.32},
    {"ALL": 104.959999},
    ...
 ]
```

Actually, I lied, a rate should look like this:

```
{ "key": "AED",
  "value": 3.6733 
}
```

Edit: 
To sort the results, store them first into an object with a String field and a Double field, then you can sort them by name and display them in order.

Comment: So I should save this json file into the raw folder in Android, and then edit it so it looks like what you have shown? Because this is not my json. Another user directed me to this site :)

Comment: Well, I assumed you had control of the JSON, if you don't then you're just going to have to manually convert the unsorted format into a model you can sort.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the android documentation, it says:

> Returns an iterator of the String names in this object. The returned
>   iterator supports remove, which will remove the corresponding mapping
>   from this object. If this object is modified after the iterator is
>   returned, the iterator's behavior is undefined. **The order of the keys
>   is undefined.**

Therefore, you must use a different method. Perhaps try `JSONObject.names()` ? Or maybe, just add all the key-value pairs to an array, then sort it, and use that order, since it looks like it's only a simple alphabetical sort.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the android documentation. I will try what you have said first, because I don't want to use a file, I want the application to access the web.